# How to access property in SwiftUI wrapper that conforms to UIViewRepresentable?

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to control an instance of a `AVPlayer` that is instantiated and assigned to a property in the class `VideoPlayer` which conforms to `UIView`. To make sure it's clear what my intent is, I've put together a known pattern when dealing with `SwiftUI` and `UIViewRepresentable` wrappers, as follows:

```
class VideoPlayer: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var previewTimer: Timer?
    var previewLength: Double
    var player: AVPlayer?
    
    init(frame: CGRect, url: URL, previewLength:Double) {
        self.previewLength = previewLength
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        self.player?.volume = 0
        self.player?.play()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            self?.player?.play()
        }
        
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        previewTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: previewLength, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.player?.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(1)))
        })
        
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.previewLength = 15
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

The wrapper `MyWrapper` exposes the `UIView` to SwiftUI, and the `wrapper` can have public properties for example `myState`:

```
struct MyWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    var videoURL: URL
    var previewLength: Double
    @Binding var mySate: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(frame: .zero, url: videoURL, previewLength: previewLength)
        return videoPlayer
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if myState {
          // do something
        } else {
          // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

If required to control a property of the instance `VideoPlayer`, we might be tempted to access properties directly from the `UIView` object in the method `updateUIView`. So, let's say that hypothetically we want to access the `player` property:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    if myState {
      uiView.player.play()
    }
}
```

This fails with the error `Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'player'`.

To overcome this created a proxy in the `MyWrapper` to reference the `AVPlayer` instance, as follows:

```
struct MyWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    var videoURL: URL
    var previewLength: Double
    @State var player: AVPlayer?
    @Binding var play: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(frame: .zero, url: videoURL, previewLength: previewLength)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.player = videoPlayer.player
        }
        return videoPlayer
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if play {
            self.player?.play()
        } else {
            self.player?.pause()
            self.player?.rate = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Obs: We use the `DispatchQueue.main` to bypass a warning `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behaviour` that'd be thrown in `makeUIView`.

This approach works but I haven't found any documentation in Apple confirming that this is the right approach when dealing with SwiftUI and `UIViewRepresentable` wrappers, as SwiftUI is a black box.

So, for this reason I'd like to know how to access a property in SwiftUI wrapper that conforms to UIViewRepresentable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIViewRepresentable` infers type, in this case, from declared return/argument type, so just highlight explicitly what type is represented

```
struct MyWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    var videoURL: URL
    var previewLength: Double
    @Binding var mySate: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> VideoPlayer {
        let videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(frame: .zero, url: videoURL, previewLength: previewLength)
        return videoPlayer
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: VideoPlayer, context: Context) {
        if myState {
          uiView.player.play()    // now it knows that uiView is-a VideoPlayer
        } else {
          // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is brilliant, spot on! The issue here was not declaring the correct type for `SwiftUI` type-checker to work. In any other case where X conforms to Y, we should always declare a very specific type. There's probably a good read on this that I missed out? as this might be common sense when dealing with type inference (when not to rely on it, it seems clear now that SwiftUI wouldn't really guess `UIView` has property `X` unless declared). Thanks a lot!